# BUILDROOT ip: can't find device eth0

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, buildroot

I have problem with network in buildroot on my VirtualMachine. When i typing ifconfig i get answer:

eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

While loading buildroot on console i see:

ip: can't find device eth0

ip: SI0CGIFFALGS :No such device

I cant`t find the way resolve this problem.

Comment: Buildroot is a tool for producing a toolchain, kernel and root filesystem.  Your first sentence, *"I have problem with network in buildroot"*, makes no sense.  Did you use Buildroot to make the kernel & rootfs that you running in a VM?  How did you configure the kernel?  What's the `dmesg` output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# make linux-menuconfig

Device drivers —>
Network device support —>
Ethernet driver support—>
```

Select:

```
<*>     Intel(R) PRO/100+ support                                
<*>     Intel(R) PRO/1000 Gigabit Ethernet support               
<*>     Intel(R) PRO/1000 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support    
<*>     Intel(R) 82575/82576 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support
[*]     Intel(R) PCI-Express Gigabit adapters HWMON support  
<*>     Intel(R) 82576 Virtual Function Ethernet support
```

And should work now with VM.

Comment: I changed Adapter type in VB and it has resolved a problem.
VB -> Network -> Advanced -> Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop(EM)
Thx fo answers.

Comment: At letter versions of VB this is selected by default. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not a Buildroot problem, but a kernel configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the last line in the boot log, you might add `Intel(R) PRO/1000 PCI-Express Gigabit Ethernet support` as @TadejP mentioned.

```
[    0.204512] e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
[    0.205444] e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    0.220165] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11
[    0.362077] ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    0.362908] ata1.00: 4280320 sectors, multi 16: LBA48
[    0.364110] ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    0.365246] ata2.00: configured for MWDMA2
[    0.366176] ata1.00: configured for MWDMA2
[    0.366846] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.368118] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4280320 512-byte logical blocks: (2.19 GB/2.04 GiB)
[    0.369219] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    0.369916] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    0.371218] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    0.372213] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.387384]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    0.388409] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[    0.389298] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    0.390163] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    0.390976] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    0.548201] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 52:54:00:12:34:56
[    0.549265] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
```